# Checking the result of sampling mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the study, I got stuck at one point. Trying to check if a value exists in MongoDB db collection documents using Mongoose.
I have a separate function that searches for a DB entry using findOne.
If we remove everything unnecessary from the code, it looks something like this:

```
const checkUserExist = async (userName) => {
  return await userModel.findOne ({userName});
};


const validateRegistrationData = (inputData) => {

const {userName} = inputData;

const userExist = checkUserExist (userName);

if (userExist) {
console.log ('User found')
}
 else {
 console.log ('User not found')
}
};
```

The problem is that it always returns true in this case.

I tried a couple more options:

```
 if (! userName) {
}
 if (userName === null) {
}
if (userName! == null) {
}
if (userName === undefined) {
}
if (userName! == undefined) {
}
```

Document Model:

```
const userSchema = new Schema (
{
userName: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
name: {type: String, required: true},
email: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
encryptedPassword: {type: String, required: true},
},
);
```

This is clearly a newbie mistake, but I did not find any clear information on this on the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're not awaiting the `checkUserExist()` method. Because that method returns a promise, your `if` statement will always result to true. If you convert `validateRegistrationData()` to an `async` method and `await` the call to `checkUserExist()` it should work as expected.

Something like this:

```
const validateRegistrationData = async (inputData) => {
    const {userName} = inputData;
    const userExist = await checkUserExist(userName);

    if (userExist) {
        console.log ('User found')
    } else {
        console.log ('User not found')
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh, it was that simple. I tried the given solution, then it did not work due to another error of mine. Now I fixed everything and it works, thanks.